# How to solve such a modular equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have an equation as follows: 
$27217 = 5s $ mod $42547$

Using this website https://www.dcode.fr/modular-equation-solver, the correct result for s is 39481 as shown below however it does not list what steps are being done.

[Solving modular equation using dCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt7Sr.png)

How would one go about to find the value of s in this modular equation?

Comment: You need the multiplicative inverse of $5$ modulo $42547$, which can be found out with the extended-Euclid-Algorithm.

Comment: Unfortunately that link didn't help much because the structure of that equation is different than mine and the unknown value is on the left hand side whereas mine is on the right. 

@Peter I also thought of using EEA but the multiplicative inverse of 5 modulo 42547 is 17019 which does not match the result found from the website in my post.

Comment: It does not matter on which side the variable is. If $27217=5s \mod 42547$ then $5s=27217 \mod 42547$. The mod is not a function - it denotes that the whole equation to its left is to be evaluated modulo that number.

Comment: @Mulishia The multiplicative inverse must be multiplied with the number on the left side mod 42547

Comment: You have $42547 = 157\cdot 271.$  You can reduce mod each of these factors and solve.  Then use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have figured it out now.

Answer (score 0):

We must have that $$5s-27217=42547t$$for some integer $t$. Therefore $$5(s-5443-8509t)=2t+2$$thereby dividing $27217$ and $42547$ over $5$. By defining $q=5-5443-8509t$ we obtain the following easy-to-solve equation$$5q=2t+2$$which has an answer $q=2$ and $t=4$ yielding to $$s=39481$$therefore all the answers can be found as follows $$s=39481+42547k\quad,\quad k\in \Bbb Z$$